# Black screen using Vuforia AR Camera for desktop app

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm developing an AR application (using the Vuforia plugin) for a Windows PC connected to a webcam. Everything works fine in the game preview: Unity opens the webcam view and I'm able to see my virtual object placed upon the recognized object. However, when I build and run my Windows .exe the app only show a black screen after the Unity splash. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: did you find a solution for this??